# Is there a way to get data from 2 tables without creating a Cartesian product?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In our database a customer can have any number of drivers, any number of vehicles, any number of storage locations, any number of buildings at those locations, any number of comments, and so on. I need a query that returns **all** of the customer's information and right now the query is something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Driver d ON c.ID = d.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Vehicle v ON c.ID = v.CustomerID
```

The more that a customer has the bigger the result gets, and it grows exponentially because a cartesian product is being created here. 3 drivers, 3 vechiles creates 9 rows, and this is a very small example compared to what our real data is like. We actually have 10 different tables that can hold as many rows per customer as they want. The norm is 2-7 rows at least per table per customer. we have had as many as 60,000,000+ rows returned (6 items each in 10 different tables, 6^10 = 60,466,176) and for our purposes 6 rows total would have given us all the data we needed if we could just ***stick*** the 6 rows in each table together.

so in the smaller example, if 1 customer had 2 vehicles and 3 drivers and another customer had 2 vehicles and 1 drivers i would want a result set that looked like:

```
CustomerID  | DriverID | VehicleID
1           | 1        | 1
1 (or NULL) | 2        | 2
1 (or NULL) | NULL     | 3
2           | 3        | 4
2 (or NULL) | 4        | NULL
```

Instead our query that joins every table together on CustomerID looks like this:

```
CustomerID | DriverID | VehicleID
1          | 1        | 1
1          | 1        | 2
1          | 1        | 3
1          | 2        | 1
1          | 2        | 2
1          | 2        | 3
2          | 3        | 4
2          | 4        | 4
```

Really, what I want to do is just:

```
SELECT * FROM Driver
SELECT * FROM Vehicle
```

Because all we are doing with the data is looping through the rows and formatting the information in a document. All drivers are listed, then all vehicles are listed. It makes no sense to do this crazy huge join when we don't have to, but it's just an arbitrary requirement that it must return all the data in 1 result set from a stubborn superior who refuses to listen to reason. Since the columns are different a UNION isn't possible. i'm just hoping there's a way to stick them together horizontally instead of vertically.

Also, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Do you really need the data returned as individual rows? What do you use it for afterwards? You could use an operator which aggregate drivers into a pseudocolumn, vehicles in another, etc etc and group by customer ID, no?

Comment: How do you know that Driver one only is associated with vehicle 1? Each driver could be associated with each vehicle, which is what your query is showing.   Is there some additional field(s) to describe the other links (i.e. drive 1 gets vehicle 1)

Comment: Sparky, drivers and vehicles have no association. They are both associated to the customer. I don't care which vehicles are on the same row with which drivers, all I care about is that every vehicle and every driver is in the results.

Comment: fge, what do you mean by pseudocolumn? I am not familiar with that.

Comment: So you want to make sure every related ID is included only once?, not the combinations?   A pseudo column is essentially a calculation done as part of a query (non-technical answer), such as quantity*price as Total_order_price

Comment: Yes, that's is correct. I don't want the combinations.

And, oh, then I use pseudocolumns all the time I just didn't know they were called that. How could I use pseudocolumns to solve this problem, though?

Comment: @Nick this is what I was talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: That would not work, I still need to be able to access individual columns.

Comment: An `INNER JOIN` is **not** a cartesian product!

Comment: A Cartesian product is a product of 2 sets. When you have 3 drivers for a customer and 3 vehicles for a customer and your result is 9 rows, 1 row for every possible combination of those 3 drivers and 3 vehicles, that absolutely is the text-book definition of a Cartesian product. My set is not every vehicle in the table, it's every vehicle for a customer. so it's a smaller Cartesian product, but a Cartesian product none-the-less.

Comment: Nick, you are wrong and @a_horse_with_no_name is right. An `INNER JOIN` is **not** a Cartesian product. It's not being "nitpicky about semantics." Let's not bastardize  mathematical definitions, please.

Comment: What are you talking about? It's a simple definition to find, especially using the Interet: Cartesian prouduct - noun - Mathematics - A set of all pairs of elements (x,y) that can be constructed form given sets, X and Y, such that x belongs to X and y belongs to Y. Set X = Drivers for customer 1. Set Y = Vehicles for customer 1. A set of all ordered pairs of those 2 sets is literally **by definition** a Cartesian product. You say "let's not bastardize mathematical definitions" but that's exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @NullUserException: `INNER JOIN` is not a mathematical definition. In SQL, `INNER JOIN` is a specialized Cartesian product e.g. can one may re-write an `INNER JOIN` using product (`CROSS JOIN`) and restriction (`WHERE`). Consider that Codd's algebra had product and restriction but no `JOIN` operator yet was still relationally complete (a rename operator aside). `CROSS JOIN` is not a Cartesian product because it doesn't produce pairs (I don't know what to call what does produce, though!) And yes, this is mere nitpicking about semantics :)

Comment: Your query is the correct best way to do this. I don't even see why you have a problem with it.

Comment: I have a problem with it because it returns more than 60 million rows. and after joining to 10 different tables there are over 500 columns. that's more than 30 billion cells or pieces of data.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I can use a pseudocolumn for row number of each item for the same customer and then full outer join the tables on customerID and row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'm doing it. Instead of:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Driver d ON c.ID = d.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Vehicle v ON c.ID = v.CustomerID
```

I'm doing:

```
WITH CustomerCTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 ROW_NUM, ID
  FROM Customer
),
DriverCTE AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) ROW_NUM, *
  FROM Driver
),
VehicleCTE AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) ROW_NUM, *
  FROM Vehicle
)
SELECT *
FROM CustomerCTE c
FULL OUTER JOIN DriverCTE d ON c.ID = d.CustomerID AND c.ROW_NUM = d.ROW_NUM
FULL OUTER JOIN VehicleCTE v ON d.CustomerID = v.CustomerID AND d.ROW_NUM = v.ROW_NUM
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN c.ID IS NOT NULL THEN c.ID ELSE
  CASE WHEN d.CustomerID IS NOT NULL THEN d.CustomerID ELSE
    v.CustomerID
  END
END,
CASE WHEN c.ROW_NUM IS NOT NULL THEN c.ROW_NUM ELSE
  CASE WHEN d.ROW_NUM IS NOT NULL THEN d.ROW_NUM ELSE
    v.ROW_NUM
  END
END
```

Now if a customer has 3 drivers and 3 vehicles i get 3 rows instead of 9 rows. It makes it look like each driver is associated to 1 of the 3 vehicles, but it's actually not. Again, this is bad design, but it is necessary to cut down on the number of rows returned with the unreasonable restrictions I was given.

It looks like more work than webturner's answer, but in my real case where I have to join 10 different tables with over 500 columns its a lot less work to do it this way than to explicitly name all 500 columns and fill in all of the remaining columns from each table with NULL.

Though, this may not be of much use to most people. In most cases if you're doing something like this you probably need to rethink your design, but there may be some cases where you have no choice.

Answer (score 3):

It's an ugly hack, but you know your proper solution is just as you state:

```
SELECT * FROM Driver
SELECT * FROM Vehicle
```

Instead you could use a union query and blank out the columns from the other tables, just start it with a query that sets the type and names of the columns, with a false coldition so it doesn't return a row:

```
SELECT 1 AS DriverID, "" AS DriverName, 1 AS VehicleID, "" AS VehicleName WHERE 1=0 
UNION SELECT DriverID, DriverName, NULL, NULL FROM Driver
UNION SELECT NULL, NULL, VehicleID, VehicleName FROM Driver
```

Really, really bad code! Keep working on your superior to allow a better solution.

Comment: +1 I agree this is an ugly hack but, given the circumstances, it's what I would have proposed as well. :)

Comment: The example I gave is tiny compared to the amount of data we actually have. After joining to all 10 tables we can easily have well over 500 columns. manually naming each column and typing all those nulls would be a huge pain.